# SSIS package shows blank screen in design mode

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I created an SSIS package using SQL Server Data Tools 2015 a week back.
And today I opened the package and it just shows the blank screen.

I read about this issue [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5b4faddc-5723-44fb-926d-e5a92dc8fc0f/ssis-designer-is-solid-white?forum=sqlintegrationservices) and it seems that was the defect in earlier versions and it is fixed.

Has anyone faced this issue in SQL Server Data Tools? How can I fix it and save my package?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

1. While the package is opened with the white page, rename it in the solution.
2. Save the package and close.
3. Rename the package back original name (while package is closed). This rename will open the package and hopefully set it back so that you can edit it.

Comment: #2 gives "Object reference not set to an object" error but this still works.

Answer (score 14):

All white on open? Just happens from time to time, the stuff is there just close and reopen Visual Studio always makes it come back for me.

But if not you could always find the dtsx file under it all in your users folder:

```
C:\Users\<yourusernamehere>\Source\Workspaces\<Projectworkspace>
```

copy it and then pull it back in by right clicking the SSIS Packages folder in Solution Explorer and add existing package see if you can see it then.

Comment: Closing VS always works for me but we shouldn't have to still be doing this. Also, it does not work for some people.

See here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1347837

but there is no resolve on this and no link to duplicate. My guess is MS don't know how to fix it but we should all create more and more connect tickets until they do. (power in numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Tim's answer above helped but didnt work for me.  Instead this worked in Visual Studio 2015:

1. Close the solution
2. Move the .dtsx file that will not open to another folder (ex: C:\Temp)
3. Rename the .dtsx file to the name you want
4. Open the solution - you should get a message that the package is missing.
5. In Solution Explorer, right-click on "SSIS Packages" and select "Add existing Package"
6. Package Location should be "File system".  Click the "..." button and select the moved and renamed .dtsx file.  click OK

The .dtsx file should now be added in the solution correctly named - and open for editing.

Comment: This trick has worked for me in the past, but it did not work today. I believe the problem lies in one of the other files created at the time of build -- a file in bin or obj folders, or maybe one of the files with the suffix ".database" or ".dtproj". My fix today was to create a new solution in VS and use the SSIS import to pull the packages off of the server from the existing deployment. That was OK for me, as the deployment had the latest code. FWIW I suspect my use of DropBox and its synch are sometimes causing this problem for me, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The rename and reopen trick worked for me. I also tried another way. I closed Visual Studio and then located the .suo file under the .vs folder. I deleted that and then reopened and the file reloaded.
I hope that isn't too dangerous an approach; it stops git changes being made when the rename is performed

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the trick to rename the package. It works as long as I keep a new name, but when I rename the package back to its old name, the problem returns. Importing a new copy of the .dtsx file into the same (broken) project did not fix the problem. [Referring to answer by @Joe]

Here is the only solution that *always* works for me:

1. Create a new Visual Studio (or SSDT) solution.
2. At the new project dialogue, choose "Integration Services Import Project Wizard"
3. A wizard starts up [hit next if at optional "Wizard Introduction"]
4. At "Select Source" page choose "Integration Services Catalog"
5. Browse to server and the project deployment you need to fix

This works, but if your deployed SSIS package(s) was not up to date you need to continue with these two actions:

- Delete the package(s) in the new (fixed) solution that are old.
- Import the newer package(s) via "Add Existing Package" from the problematic solution

I suspect this happens due to a problem in the .database or .dtproj file.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered this; solution opens but all blank and no sub folders or files in the Solution Explorer. Tried the above suggestions, but no luck. Right clicked on the solution name and selected 'Reload Project' and all good.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

In the Solution Explorer right click on the .dtsx package file and then click on View Designer.